# Is it possible to automatically activate remember-me upon OAuth2 in Grails 2.3

Tags: grails, remember-me, spring-security-oauth2

I integrated the `spring-security-oauth` plugin into my app, and the login over FB or Google seems to be working fine.

The problem I have now, is that the authentication expires along with the tomcat session, which is not what it should be. I want the OAuth-authentication to be persistent on client's machine. Some sort of spring security's `remember-me` functionality is needed.

Is there a possibility to activate it out-of-box?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after doing some research and talking the plugin creator here http://github.com/enr/grails-spring-security-oauth/issues/9, the solution was found. It will be available in the upcoming release, or you can do it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I have this setup in my application.  What you want to do is enable rememberme configuration:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#rememberMeCookie

run the s2-create-persistent-token script

```
In config file:
rememberMe.alwaysRemember = true // by default it is false
rememberMe.persistent = true // by default it is off
```

I don't have my application on hand but if you need exact configs, let me know and I'll post it up later for you.

Comment: that's not exactly what I need. Apart from oauth I have a plain login flow, where "remember me" function is optional